# Update price and quantity with rest api

Tags: magento2, product, api

I had tried to update price of single item & I got below error

> **message:** '%fieldName is a required field.'

I have used below url-

> "http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/products/{sku}".

```
method:"PUT"
body:{"items":{
       "price":50
        }
     };
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the json body as shown below:

```
{
 "product":
 {
   "price":123
 }
}
```